# How to check a condition if it was true then insert some thing at race condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

We have an api function which check a condition on database with a select-query then if it was true we want just for one time insert some thing to database for example inserting to database that insertion done. Problem is when we call multiple times this api-function concurrently race condition happen, in another words assume we call this function 2 times, first request check the condition it's true then second request check that and it's true again so their do insert to database. But we want to when we check condition no other one can check it again until we do insertion.

We use php/Laravel and know about some ways like using `insert into ... select` or using some thing like `replace into ...` and so on.

```
$order = Order::find($orderId);
$logRefer = $order->user->logrefer;
if (!is_null($logRefer) && is_null($logRefer->user_turnover_id)) {
     $userTurnover = new UserTurnover();
     $userTurnover->user_id = $logRefer->referrer_id;
     $userTurnover->order_id = $order->id;
     $userTurnover->save();

     $logRefer->order_id = $order->id;
     $logRefer->user_turnover_id = $userTurnover->id;
     $logRefer->save();
}
```

If `logrefer` not found set it and corresponding `user-turnover` just for one time. We expect to see just one `user-turnover` related to this order but after running it multiple time concurrently we see multiple `user-turnover` has inserted.

Comment: the only safe way to prevent race conditions (duplicated data in this case) which i assume this question is about is to add some (mullticolumn) UNIQUE key in the table..

Comment: Is not any php way?

Comment: *"Is not any php way?"* Well i think Laravel also has some locking methods but the database can do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually take advantage of transaction when operations need to be sequential but i think that in your case the situation it's a bit complex due to the fact that also the condition need to be evaluated conditionally if the function it's running. So the idea that i can give you it's to have on the database a variable (another table) used as semaphore which allow or not to perform actions on the table (condition gived by the fact that you set or unset the value of the semaphore). I think as good programmer that semaphore are useful in a lot of cases of concurrential functions.

Comment: Can you tell more about how to implement semaphore using a variable on another table for example?

Comment: Simple we have a table (thaht we use only for this purpose so it will contain just one row) : sem_user(val varchar(1)) is wich we can set val (to "S" for example) when we you want to lock your code  or unset val (null) if action are completed and new one can be executed. Make sure you rapidly set/unset val into a transaction , maybe make a funtion SetUnsetSemaphore() which will do for you the work. Make another function for reading current status of val , LoadValSemphoreUser().

Comment: So basically you can wrap your code into this logical flow : 1-  SetUnsetSemaphore();   2 -  if(LoadValSemphoreUser() = null) {  //your code...}  3 - SetUnsetSempahore();  Obviusly this is not exat code , this is only for giving you the idea of what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

The database should have a unique key on columns expected to be unique, even if some mechanism in the code prevents duplicates.

Wrap connected queries into a transaction which will fail and roll back in a race event condition

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function() {
        $order = Order::find($orderId);
        ...
        $logRefer->save();
    });
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
    Log::error(“failed to write to database”);
}
```

Comment: That's right but this will solve my current problem. I'm looking for a way to solve more complex problems like this